# How to remove compare products repetition in Magento

Tags: magento

While clicking on "Orders and Returns" in the footer of ever page,  Compare products was displaying twice. Anybody help me to remove one among them.

Comment: I would be glad to help,  however,  I need more information.  First I need to see the problem, then I can help give some advice.

Comment: I moved the compare products from right side column to left side column. But by default another compare products column was present in the orders and returns. So the repetition occurred. I commented one among them in the code. Now its working properly. Thanks Rob for taking initiative.

Comment: I commented line:238 in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml